# Safe working with multiple *.ini in php

Tags: php, configuration

Im facing with Ubuntu PHP configuration. There is main php.ini file and directory where are stored more *.ini files.

**QUESTION 1:** How the PHP loading this *.ini files?

- Load first php.ini and then on some place another files?
- If so in which position in php.ini or in which order?

**QUESTION 2:** How PHP order files in ini directory? It seems alphabetically but are there other "system" than its file name?

**QUESTION 3:** Why Ubuntu default installation insert into additional `*.ini` only loading directives `extension=nameofextesion.so` and configuration of this extension leave in `php.ini`? Are there any reason to split loading module and its configuration?

**Example:**
`20-mysql.ini` contains loafing mysql extension.

```
extension=mysql.so
```

`php.ini` contains `mysql.*` directives. Eg.

```
mysql.allow_local_infile = On
mysql.allow_persistent = On
etc.
```

Untill now I worked with single php.ini so this is new questions for me.
Thanks for any opinion or best practices.

cervenak

Comment: 1) there's directives in php.ini to "include" things from other directories 2) `ls` will name sort for you, PHP may or may not do the same when it looks for and lads the files 3) ease of maintenance. want to remove GD? Gee, you can't, because the gd directives are stuck in a huge monolithic .ini file. OH/ you have separate ones? `rm gd.ini` done.

Comment: 3) I dont understand your arguments Marc. Because of huge configuration is better to split into logical ini files instead to keep it together in big `php.ini` file. When I want to remove eg. GD just move the file `gd.ini` in another directory (including all of related directives). Why to parse and keep GD directives in php.ini when module is not loaded. Agree?

Answer (score 6):

In order

1. `php.ini` is generally loaded first. Note this message in the stock `php.ini` under **Dynamic Extensions**

   > ; Note: packaged extension modules are now loaded via the .ini files
   >   ; found in the directory /etc/php.d; these are loaded by default.
2. Files are loaded alphanumerically, hence why you have `10-mysql.ini`, `20-opcache.ini`, etc
3. The reason for the splitting into separate configs is so you can use a package manager (i.e. apt-get, yum, etc) to install and uninstall the "extra" parts of PHP that are not core (i.e. `php-mbstring`). In other words, this takes the place of having to compile PHP with your specific options turned on. The packages then install themselves into separate files that are autoloaded. If you uninstall that package, these extra configs will also be removed.

Comment: 1. I have red it, that it is **loaded by default**. But the question is where. **Before**, **After** `php.ini` or somewhere **middle**. If in the middle `php.ini` what is the "include" directive?

Comment: They're loaded after `php.ini`. I confirmed it by adding an extension to php.ini that was already in its own ini file and got a warning that it was already defined

Comment: Helpful. Thanks. **Supplementary question:** So I can define directives in WHATEVER order and lately load the module. Right? The only what generates the "fatal error" is loading module **A** which require module **B**. Before the **B** is loaded. Are there any other ordering rules in php.ini configuration except the loading modules?

Comment: I would use separate files in `/etc/php.d` in that instance. That way you can be sure of the load order

Answer (score 1):

The php.ini file can exist as a single php.ini file, however there are advantages to using the multiple file way.

My preference is that I enable modules using separate files located in `/etc/php.d/` *(this path may be different on your installation, but for the purpose of this response I will refer to it in this directory)*, however I also add all the configuration options in there as well as it makes it much easier to find the options this way as well.

For example I would do the following to enable opcache.

> /etc/php.d/opcache.ini

```
zend_extension=opcache.so

opcache.enable = 1
opcache.enable_cli = 1
opcache.memory_consumption = 1024
opcache.max_accelerated_files = 65536
opcache.revalidate_freq = 3600
```

As for the order which it loads it, it will load the `php.ini` file first, followed by the files in `/etc/php.d/` in alphabetical order. If there are duplicate configurations, the ones in `/etc/php.d/` will override those in `php.ini`.

There are other files which can be considered as well depending on your environment and they are described in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php)

Comment: Q3: Yes I want to write the configuration like you. First load configuration then configure it. What was confusing was the Ubuntu behavior where directives lies on php.ini.

Comment: both ways work, effectively the configuration is just ignored in the php.ini file since no module is loaded to make use of those settings. as mentioned by @Machavity when you install with a package manager they just add support for the module, and then it uses either defaults or ones in the php.ini file.

Comment: **Package manager:** Im not package manager expert. But what config files - if any - can package managers changes? I have installed **xdebug** via pear and it install `xdebug.so` to the right directory. Without any default directives neither in `php.ini` nor in any separate `*.ini` file.

Comment: some packages will create a file in the `/etc/php.d/` folder some will edit the `php.ini` file, some will output a comment telling you what to do, and otherwise will just do nothing